# Correct way to get response from Slack API

Tags: ruby, slack-api

I want to move this code from the console:

```
curl --data "token=TOKEN_NO&email=USER@EXAMPLE.COM" https://slack.com/api/users.lookupByEmail
```

to the class method and get response from Slack (user details) exactly like from the console. I was trying to do something like this, but I don't see any results:

```
require 'net/http'

module Slack
  class GetUserID
    SLACK_API_ENDPOINT = 'https://slack.com/api/users.lookupByEmail'

    def call
      escaped_address = URI.decode_www_form_component(SLACK_API_ENDPOINT)
      uri = URI.parse(escaped_address)
      puts Net::HTTP.post(uri, params)
    end

    private

    def params
      {
        token: 'TOKEN_NO',
        email: 'USER@EXAMPLE.COM'
      }
    end
  end
end
```

Right now I have an error:

> `send_request_with_body': undefined method`bytesize' for #Hash:0x00007f9d85093100> (NoMethodError)

Where am I wrong? Should I use `HTTParty` instead?

Comment: You'll need to show the stacktrace so we can make sense of this.

Comment: I think that you need to add `.to_json` so it would look like: `puts Net::HTTP.post(uri, params.to_json)`

Answer (score 0):

The second argument passed to `Net::HTTP.post` should be a string, read more about the method signature [here](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-post).

You will need to convert the `params` hash into a query string format that looks like:

```
token=TOKEN_NO&email=USER@EXAMPLE.COM
```